# Have to plan international trip for work but might be leaving job soon

Tags: travel, resignation

I have to plan an international trip in the next few days that will be very expensive for my company that won't be for another month. But I am also far along in the interview process with another company and maybe accepting a new position before I leave for this trip and there would be no reason to make the trip if I am leaving.

I have to finish an assignment for the last step in the interview process for the potential job so I won't hear back from them for maybe 7-10 days. I don't want to ask them to rush to make their decision (and I don't think they can because they have other candidates) and I **don't** want to tell my boss I might be leaving and that is why I haven't booked my trip. What are your suggestions?

Comment: Will there be no reason at all for the trip to be made in case you are leaving or will someone else have to make the trip instead?

Comment: If it's really expensive, maybe it's a flex ticket anyway?

Answer (score 8):

Until you give notice at your current company, continue working there as if you will not be leaving.

Until your last day, you have a job with responsibilities to your company and various stakeholders. If your duties require you to book and plan a trip, book and plan the trip. If you leave the organization before your trip, the company can address that - either by cancelling the reservations or by transferring them to someone else's name as appropriate.

If your job offer falls through or if you wouldn't be expected to give notice until after your trip ends, then you would need to go on the trip for your job. If you get the job, simply give notice at the appropriate time.